# Universal descriptions for emails across different clients

Tags: html, email, meta-tags, mailchimp

Is there a universal way to set the lead-in, description, meta text for an email in email campaigns?

I'm talking about this last bit of text, as seen in Gmail on Chrome:

[image]

For this scenario I am using MailChimp, but I'd like to know if there is a universal HTML implementation that works across every mailing client.

The email in the example above contains only text, making this easy - but what if the emails don't have text (my employer loves putting just images in emails to preserve her brand's fonts) or if I simply want different text to come up. Is there a field for that? Or an HTML tag of some sort? Or anything hacky but works well?

I've tried using things like `alt` attributes on the images, using `display: none` on a `<span>` at the top and putting the description in there, and using `<meta name="description">` but nothing seems to work on all email clients.

I'm currently testing things out on my iOS Mail app, my iOS Gmail app, and Gmail in Chrome and different things come out for each with each of these implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Universal? Not really because each email client can handle it differently, but here's a really useful write-up from Litmus on the topic: https://litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-preview-text-support. They suggest adding a div right after the opening body tag to explicitly define what preview text appears:

`<body>
  <div>
    Your preview text here.
  </div>
</body>`

Comment: Yes this definitely works but the idea here is that we want to define this value without showing it to the person reading the email. In my scenario, I am either creating an email made primarily out of images, or I want to set this description to be something other than what the first line of the email should actually be. I have used `display: none` on this element, but oddly the email still displays it in most email clients.